# For the life of me can't find where terminal alias's are stored

Tags: terminal, bash, alias

So I have been playing around with aliases in bash and it is easy enough to add them.

`alias lsl="ls -l"`

My question is, where are they stored? I am using the bash shell, so I looked in the obvious places .bash_alias, .bashrc, etc... and these alias are nowhere to be found. Now, I guess if I had created a .bash_alias file they would have gone there, but since I never did, they must be stored somewhere else on my computer but I can't find them.

Can someone give me some ideas of where to look?

Comment: Are you using bash? The default is zsh and it would read from other files like .zshrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` aliases you create by running the `alias` command are not stored anywhere, they are gone as soon as you exit the shell.

To make persistant aliases which will be available in all newly executed `bash` shells add the definition to `~/.bashrc`. You can then also run `source ~/.bashrc` after adding new definitions to have them included in a running shell.

Comment: Ahh. That makes perfect sense. So once I exit the terminal they will all vanish, which would explain why I can't find them stored anywhere. Ok. Thanks for the answer!